# How to duplicate a record in Rails except for one attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In my Rails application I have a method that duplicates an `invoice` including its `items`.

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base

  def duplicate
    dup.tap do |new_invoice|
      new_invoice.date = Date.today
      new_invoice.number = nil              <<<--------------
      items.each do |item|
        new_invoice.items.push item.dup
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Now what I would like is to **not copy** the `number` attribute at all, so a new `number` can be generated inside my `new` action (I am not showing that here for brevity).

Right now, I am setting it to `nil` which is not what I want.

Any Ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the new number as a parameter, it's the most simple and most readable technique

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  def duplicate(new_number = nil)
    dup.tap do |new_invoice|
      new_invoice.date = Date.today
      new_invoice.number = new_number
      items.each do |item|
        new_invoice.items.push item.dup
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then in your controller

```
class InvoicesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    ...
    @new_invoice = @invoice.duplicate(new_number)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. This is actually what I had before and ended up with ultimately.

Answer (score 6):

Something along these lines perhaps:

```
def duplicate
  new_invoice = Invoice.new(attributes.except("id", "number"))
  items.each do |item|
    new_invoice.items.push item.dup
  end
  new_invoice
end
```

Or loop over the attributes if you need to get around protected attributes etc. But `self.attributes` with [Hash#except](http://apidock.com/rails/Hash/except) is probably what you want.

Comment: Neat trick, but I've found that the `attributes` keys are actually strings, so you'd need: `attributes.except("number")`

Comment: Oh and `new` doesn't replace the database ID automatically, so you need to exclude that too!

Answer (score 0):

Why not

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  def clone
    number = self.number
    cloned = super
    cloned.number = number
  end
end
```